# Javascript Convert Textarea input to Array to calculate average total

Tags: javascript, arrays, average

I am trying to get the script to calculate the average from numbers entered into a text area. The numbers are seperated by a comma

I either get a NaN value or it just doesnt work right.

This code came closest to actually working. However it only adds the comma as a new element and all numbers are just combined in the first element, dividing the number by the amount of comma's.

```js
document.querySelector("#input").addEventListener("input", function test() {
  const strng = document.getElementById("input").value;
  var arr = strng.split(',');

  const avg = arr.reduce((a, b) => a + b, 0) / arr.length;
  document.getElementById("lbl").innerHTML = avg;
});


function cycle() {
  var area = document.getElementById("txt").value;
  var lines = area.split(',');

  const average = arr => arr.reduce((a, b) => a + b, 0) / arr.length;

  document.getElementById("lbl").innerHTML = average([lines]).toFixed(2);

}
setInterval(cycle, 100)
```

```html
<textarea id="input"></textarea>
<label id="lbl">Result Here</label>
<textarea id="txt"></textarea>
```

The `cycle()` function gave me a NaN value right after entering the first comma in the textarea.

Can someone help me out?

Comment: May I please understand why one requires `setInterval` in this context? Do you need to update the average as & when user enters numbers into the `text-area`? If so: we may explore using event handler/s to address this.

Comment: That is indeed better. I am just learning to use javascript and this is how I used to call to functions. I have added an event handler to my code.

Comment: Have added an answer with (what I believe to be) sufficient comments/description. Feel free to ask any further questions & someone from our community may be able to help both of us learn. :-)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```js
// access the DOM elements
const inpTxt = document.getElementById("input");
const outTxt = document.getElementById("lbl");

// add event listener to text-area "input" event
inpTxt.addEventListener("input", () => {
  // collect the list of comma separated numbers into an array "numList"
  const numList = inpTxt
    .value                    // access the DOM element "inpTxt"'s value attribute
    .split(',')               // ".split()" using "comma" as the seperator
    .map(Number)              // convert each element into a number
    .filter(                  // sanity check to remove any non-number data
      x => !isNaN(x)
    );
  console.log(numList);       // to see in real-time the "numList" array on console
  if (numList.length) {       // if there are any valid numbers in the array
    outTxt.innerText = (      // change the "label"'s innerText
      numList.reduce(         // sum the numbers in the "numList" array
        (total, num) => total + num,
        0                     // initialize the "sum" to zero
      ) /                     // divide into "numList.length" to compute average
      numList.length
    );
  }
});
```

```html
<div>
  Type comma-separated numbers in below input box
  and average will be calculated
</div>
<div><textarea id="input"></textarea></div>
<div><label id="lbl">Result Here</label></div>
```

Comment: I have studied your instructions and I understand it much better now. It all works! Thank you very much!

Answer (score 2):

When you split a string from user input you get an array of strings. Thus you have to parse these strings into numbers and filter out any non numeric values before calculation.

```js
function test() {
  const inputValue = document.getElementById("input").value;
  var values = inputValue.split(',').map(v => parseFloat(v)).filter(v => !Number.isNaN(v));

  const avg = values.reduce((a, b) => a + b, 0) / values.length;

  document.getElementById("lbl").innerHTML = (!Number.isNaN(avg)) ? avg : '';
}

setInterval(test, 100);
```

```html
<textarea id="input"></textarea><br>
<label id="lbl">Result Here</label>
<textarea id="txt"></textarea>
```

Comment: As an aside, you'd be better to replace the OP's `setInterval` approach with an event approach whereby when the textarea changes, you fire the code.

Comment: Thank you, I have added this to the code.